# How to update values of a row in a table after polling for new incoming data in a loop

Tags: java, jquery, oop, message-queue, polling

I had already implemented polling for this database in java and reads all incoming data which resides in the outgoingqueue. Now I have problems in updating the polled rows, which is like I just change some values in rows, So

My question is :

1.How to loop for the rows in this table such that it has the value of ACTION=804 and has the highest SEQ value.

2.How to update the rows by just changing the values in KEYINFO1 & KEYINFO2 for the table below.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/24/updatinganamolies.png/

[image]

Here is the code which does polling and checks for new incoming message

```
    public void run() { // run method calls the fullpoll() 
    int seqId = 0;
    while(true) {
        List<KamMessage> list = null;
        try {
            list = fullPoll(seqId);
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                seqId = list.get(0).getSequence();
                incomingQueue.addAll(list);
                this.outgoingQueue = incomingQueue;
                System.out.println("waiting 3 seconds");
                System.out.println("new incoming message");
                Thread.sleep(3000);
                MessageProcessor processor = new MessageProcessor() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        generate(dbConnection);

                    }
                };


            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


       }
     }

    public List<KamMessage> fullPoll(int lastSeq) throws Exception {
    Statement st = dbConnection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from msg_new_to_bde where ACTION =  804 and 
            SEQ >" + lastSeq + "order by SEQ DESC");  
    List<KamMessage> pojoCol = new ArrayList<KamMessage>();
    try {


        while (rs.next()) {
            KpiMessage filedClass = convertRecordsetToPojo(rs);
            pojoCol.add(filedClass);
        }

        for (KpiMessage pojoClass : pojoCol) {
            System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getSequence());
            System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getTableName());
            System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getAction());
            System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo1());
            System.out.print(" " + pojoClass.getKeyInfo2());
            System.out.println(" " + pojoClass.getEntryTime());
        }


    } finally  {
        rs.close();
        st.close();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

So here is my example code which am using for generating a row, but how to update this row by having the condition such that it has highest SEQ and ACTION value=804

```
    public void generate()
    {
        KpiMsg804 upd= createKpiMsg804();
        while(true){
            try {
                st = conn.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Updating Values");
        String query = "insert into   
                        msg_new_to_bde(tablename,action,keyinfo1,keyinfo2) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";

                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
                pstmt.setString(1,upd.getTableName());
                pstmt.setInt(2,upd.getAction()); // set value of action
                pstmt.setString(3,upd.getKeyInfo1()); // set key-info value1
                pstmt.setString(4,upd.getKeyInfo2()); // set key-info value2
                int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                System.out.println("Number of Rows Created " +rows);
                // execute insert statement
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        public KpiMsg804 createKpiMsg804()
  {
 KpiMsg804 msg= new KpiMsg804();
     msg.setKeyInfo1("ENTITYKEY2");
     msg.setKeyInfo2("STATUSKEY2");
 return msg;
    }
```

how to update by just changing two values in a table for the row in sequence, by changing ENTITYKEY and STATUSKEY to ENTITYKEY1 and STATUSKEY1

I have to use a logic such that my method should look for a row with highest sequence number and corresponding ACTIONKEY, finally it updates(changes the value in) the row with a different value.

P.S : "Kind request : Pls give a reason for giving negative marks (thumbs down) . So that I can explain my question clearly"

Comment: Update the table's model using `setValueAt()`; the view should follow. If not, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.

Comment: @trashgod thank.I have updated above, as you said I also tried using setVAalueAT() aswell, but how to use a logic such that, this update method looks for data with highest sequence number and updates the row with different value...

Comment: Are you sure this is pl/sql?

Comment: I don't see any PL/SQL; `while(true)` will exceed _some_ quota eventually; maybe consider a swing `Timer`; update? insert? Sorry, I don't understand at all.

Comment: You should hoist this  code out of the loop for starters.  Very inefficient.  st = conn.createStatement();
                System.out.println("Updating Values");
        String query = "insert into   
                        msg_new_to_bde(tablename,action,keyinfo1,keyinfo2) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";

                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query); // create a statement
Also, I dont see how this loop ever terminates.  Really not sure what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @Plouf trashgod Ya am using plsql but executing this in Java. The rest was the condition as i have said...

Comment: @LeorA ya thanks mate. I could get you, its in a loop because i want give test data to feed into the database... the code what i have posted is for adding up a new row .... but my question was how to update it the polled row like just adding two values in the row.

Comment: I'm not sure I get your problem. An <code>update your_table set (keyinfo1,keyinfo2)=(select bla,blo from your_table where ...) where action_key=your_cond and seq_number= (select max(seq_number) from your_table);</code>

Comment: @Thanks mate... Ya exactly, but now as you can see my updated post, I have all the polled data in outgoing queue in (datas- pojo form not in database) in java format, I have to give a condition such that the polled data will be updated by just changing the values... how could I proceed from here...

Comment: @Babu: Ok, no idea with Java. Sorry